# Bootstrap Modal Closes on Touch for stock Android Browser

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 3+

I have a registration / login form in a modal. When you open a modal in the stock android browser the user can't touch a form or anything because it automatically closes like it would if you clicked outside of the modal area.

I have a lot of users using the default android browser for some strange reason so this is causing major issues on my website.

If anyone knows of a fix for this issue it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on button click to open the modal

$(window).scrollTop(0);